# Where can I get a list of obsolete and end-of-life software?

Tags: software

As per title.

My objective is to check a large number of Windows endpoints/hosts for existence of obsolete software. Can anyone let me know if there is a list somewhere or any software that can help me with this?

Comment: 1) by "software that can help me with this" , do you mean a tool to check if obsolete software is present? 2)What is the purpose? Is it related to compliance issues or vulnerability assessment? If not, this might be an off-topic question.

Comment: Yes. More like compliance and VA. May i know why is this off-topic?

Comment: I said it might have been off-topic, because you didn't provide any reason for checking the existence of obsolete software, and this is not necessarily a security issue. As a result, this question might have been more appropriate for other SE websites. Moreover, questions asking for product recommendations are usually not accepted (see meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/…). I suggest you to edit your question adding the reason (VA,compliance). As for the product recommendation part, let's see what the moderators have to say.

Comment: For anyone that lands here, you may want to check out: https://www.upcomingeol.com/